# Angular Primeng dropdown won't work after updating primeng to v.15

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-dropdowns

I'm working in an Angular project which uses Primeng.

After updating Primeng to version **15.1.0** the dropdown wasn't expandable anymore.
When clicking on the element this error message is showing:

[image: error message]

It's only the dropdown that doesn't work, all other input elements like checkboxes and input fields work as expected.

**How can I get the dropdown to expand on click?**

How I'm using the dropdown:

```
<p-dropdown
    [(ngModel)]="item[col.field]"
    [options]="nodeTypeOptions"
    optionLabel="name"
    optionValue="nodeType"
    (onChange)="onItemChanged(item)"
    placeholder="Välj"
    appendTo="body"
    [style]="{ width: '100%' }"
></p-dropdown>
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "lalla",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "nx",
    "postinstall": "node ./decorate-angular-cli.js && ngcc --properties es2020 browser module main",
    "start-api": "nx serve api",
    "start-dev": "nx serve lalla --proxy-config apps/lalla/proxy.conf.json",
    "build": "nx build",
    "test": "nx test",
    "test-coverage": "jest --coverage",
    "seed": "ts-node -r tsconfig-paths/register --project apps/api/tsconfig.app.json apps/api/src/seed.ts",
    "api-e2e": "jest --config ./apps/api/test/jest-e2e.json --forceExit"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.1.1",
    "@angular/common": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~15.1.1",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^5.1.2",
    "@nestjs/class-transformer": "^0.4.0",
    "@nestjs/common": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/config": "^2.2.0",
    "@nestjs/core": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/jwt": "^10.0.1",
    "@nestjs/mapped-types": "^1.2.0",
    "@nestjs/passport": "^9.0.0",
    "@nestjs/platform-express": "^9.2.1",
    "@nestjs/typeorm": "^9.0.0",
    "@nrwl/angular": "15.5.2",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "bcrypt": "^5.1.0",
    "bootstrap": "5.2.3",
    "class-validator": "^0.14.0",
    "guid-typescript": "^1.0.9",
    "passport": "^0.6.0",
    "passport-http-bearer": "^1.0.1",
    "passport-jwt": "^4.0.1",
    "pg": "^8.8.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.0",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primeng": "^15.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.4.1",
    "typeorm": "^0.3.11",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5",
    "zone.js": "~0.12.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~15.1.2",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~15.2.0",
    "@angular/cli": "~15.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~15.1.1",
    "@angular/language-service": "~15.1.1",
    "@nestjs/schematics": "^9.0.4",
    "@nestjs/testing": "^9.2.1",
    "@nrwl/cli": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/cypress": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/jest": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/linter": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/nest": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/node": "15.5.2",
    "@nrwl/workspace": "15.5.2",
    "@types/bcrypt": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/faker": "^6.6.9",
    "@types/jest": "29.2.6",
    "@types/node": "18.11.18",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.11",
    "@types/passport-jwt": "^3.0.8",
    "@types/supertest": "^2.0.12",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.48.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.48.2",
    "cypress": "^12.3.0",
    "dom-storage": "^2.1.0",
    "eslint": "~8.32.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
    "jest": "29.3.1",
    "jest-preset-angular": "~12.2.5",
    "ng-mocks": "^14.5.3",
    "nx": "15.5.2",
    "prettier": "^2.8.3",
    "supertest": "^6.3.3",
    "ts-jest": "29.0.5",
    "ts-node": "~10.9.1",
    "typescript": "~4.9.4"
  }
}
```

What I've tried:

Searched Github, stack overflow and all other webdeveloper forums for an answer, didn't find one.
Debugged the code locally but there's no constructive feedback errormessage there.
Tried to update primeng on stackblitz but to no prevail.

Expected to find a hint to where the culprit was.

Comment: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to 
[Chellappan வ](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7790376/chellappan-%E0%AE%B5) I was able to find the answer.

This was a bug in Primeng and was fixed in Primeng 15.1.1

Comment: I was looking for the solution from yesterday. Thanks it worked.